# Memory alignment while using attribute aligned(1)

Tags: c, memory-alignment

I'm debugging the following code snippet to analyze byte alignment of structure members.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

struct v_hdr {
    uint16_t vlan_tci;
    uint16_t eth_proto;
}__attribute__((aligned(1)));

struct esp_hdr {
    uint32_t fpa_esp_spi;
    uint32_t fpa_esp_sequenceid;
}__attribute__((aligned(1)));

struct f_cookie {
    uint16_t vlan_ports;
    uint16_t untagged_vlan_ports;
    struct v_hdr vlan_hdr;
    uint16_t tcp_flags;
    uint32_t *eth_hdr;
    uint32_t *ipv4_hdr;
    struct esp_hdr esp;
}__attribute__((aligned(1)));

struct metadata {
    struct f_cookie flow_cookie;
} __attribute__((aligned(1)));

int main ()
{
    struct metadata meta;
    memset (&meta, 0, sizeof(struct metadata));

    /* 16 */ meta.flow_cookie.vlan_ports             = 0xffff;
    /* 16 */ meta.flow_cookie.untagged_vlan_ports    = 0xffff;
    /* 16 */ meta.flow_cookie.vlan_hdr.vlan_tci      = 0xffff;
    /* 16 */ meta.flow_cookie.vlan_hdr.eth_proto     = 0xffff;
    /* 16 */ meta.flow_cookie.tcp_flags              = 0xffff;
    /* 32 */ meta.flow_cookie.eth_hdr                = 0xffffffff;
    /* 32 */ meta.flow_cookie.ipv4_hdr               = 0xffffffff;
    /* 32 */ meta.flow_cookie.esp.fpa_esp_spi        = 0xffffffff;
    /* 32 */ meta.flow_cookie.esp.fpa_esp_sequenceid = 0xffffffff;

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the gdb x dump before return statement -

```
(gdb) p sizeof meta
$2 = 40

(gdb) x/40bt &meta
0x7fffffffe2d0: 11111111        11111111        11111111        11111111        11111111        11111111        11111111        11111111
0x7fffffffe2d8: 11111111        11111111        00000000        00000000        00000000        00000000        00000000        00000000
0x7fffffffe2e0: 11111111        11111111        11111111        11111111        00000000        00000000        00000000        00000000
0x7fffffffe2e8: 11111111        11111111        11111111        11111111        00000000        00000000        00000000        00000000
0x7fffffffe2f0: 11111111        11111111        11111111        11111111        11111111        11111111        11111111        11111111
```

My question is why `meta.flow_cookie.eth_hdr` is not placed at 4-byte boundary after `tcp_flags`? i.e. at `(0x7fffffffe2d8 + 4)`. And `meta.flow_cookie.ipv4_hdr` not at `0x7fffffffe2e0`?

Why are both these members placed at 8-byte boundary despite applying `aligned(1)` attribute? PS. I don't want to use attribute `packed`. I just want the members to be aligned to 4-byte addresses wherever possible. Is it achievable?

Comment: GCC documentation explicitly says: *The aligned attribute can only increase the alignment; but you can decrease it by specifying packed as well.* Why do you see reason to disbelieve? And why don't you want to use `packed` if you want done what `packed`does?

Comment: @tofro: If that's the case then why is `fpa_esp_sequenceid` starting at 4-byte address? Actually `metadata` structure contains several other bit fields variables at the start. Using packed causes unaligned memory access of those variables, causing performance lag.

Comment: How is `fpa_esp_sequenceid`aligned if you **don't** specify `aligned(1)`? I pretty much doubt `aligned(1)` does *anything*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting an excerpt of your code:

> ```
> /* 16 */ meta.flow_cookie.tcp_flags              = 0xffff;
> /* 32 */ meta.flow_cookie.eth_hdr                = 0xffffffff;
> /* 32 */ meta.flow_cookie.ipv4_hdr               = 0xffffffff;
> ```

You're assuming that `meta.flow_cookie.eth_hdr` and `meta.flow_cookie.ipv4_hdr` **pointers** are 32-bit long and your system, based on your `gdb` dump, doesn't seem to be a 32-bit architecture.

Remember that `sizeof(uint32_t *)` is not the same of `sizeof(uint32_t)`. If for some reason those values are the same (in the case of a 32-bit architecture), that is pure coincidence.

A pointer will always have a size big enough to hold any address belonging to the full address space of the underlying architecture. For instance, `sizeof(uint32_t *)` on 64-bit architecture will be, at least, 8 bytes long (64-bit long).

As your architecture seems to have a 64-bit address space, the assumptions you're making for the alignments are flawed.

Comment: Thanks! This clears my doubt. `uint32_t *` is indeed 8 byte long and explains why those members are taking 8 byte.